# how to dynamically load option values in select for appendgrid jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, grid, append

Iam using [Appendgrid](http://appendgrid.apphb.com/) for data entry purpose.

one of my column in appendgrid is a input type of select.

as per the examples , one can use the select as follows

```
$('#tblAppendGrid').appendGrid({
columns:[
{ 
 name: 'Origin',
 display: 'Origin',
 type: 'select',
 ctrlOptions: { 1: 'Hong Kong', 2: 'Taiwan', 3: 'Japan', 4: 'Korea',  5: 'US', 6: 'Others'}
 }
]
});
```

but my ctrlOptions list is dynamic which i get through an api call. I get the json string as required above but when i try to substitute the json variable then i dont know why part of string till the first occurance of ":" is removed

example:

```
var data="{1:'Mango',2:'Banana',3:'Milk'}";


$('#tblAppendGrid').appendGrid({
columns:[
{ 
name: 'Origin',
display: 'Origin', 
type: 'select',
ctrlOptions:   data
}]
});
```

so this will produce a select with only one option with value 'Mango',2:'Banana',3:'Milk'}

How to i solve it to produce proper options.

Comment: also opened issue in github for it  https://github.com/hkalbertl/jquery.appendGrid/issues/64

Answer (score 0):

In your working example, ctrlOptions is not a JSON string, but it is an object. In your non-working example, ctrlOptions isn't JSON either, because it's malformed. You may have 1 or 2 issues with your code.

JSON must be formatted like this (note the quotes used): 
{"1":"Mango","2":"Banana","3":"Milk"}

Your second issue may be that your plugin doesn't accept JSON, only objects. If this is the case, you can use `JSON.parse` to convert your JSON to an object.

```
ctrlOptions: JSON.parse(data)
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle or snippet that includes jQuery and appendgrid with what you've tried?

Comment: tried to create a fiddle but it cannot load external js files , there are more than one dependencies,  This is what i could manage  http://jsfiddle.net/4v7rjmuf/  but it doesnt work there, im new to jsfiddle.. however you can see a working example demo at http://appendgrid.apphb.com/Demo     . The basic example has a select option with hard core data.. my aim is to have that data generated from some api call .

Comment: I got it to work by moving a couple things around. http://jsfiddle.net/4v7rjmuf/1/ It looks like ctrlOptions must be an object. If you look at the JS in `getJsonVendorRoles()`, you can see where I updated the string to be valid JSON and used `JSON.parse` to convert it to an object. This allows the select options to work correctly.

Comment: If you use `$.getJSON()` to retrieve the data, that is shorthand for the jQuery `$.ajax` function using JSON datatypes and returns the result as an object. I'm not sure which server side technology you are using, but just make sure that you are returning valid JSON.